# Use VIM Visual Block to concatenate blocks

Tags: vim

I try to use VIM build my SQL query by concatenate block of strings. For example, I have the following strings in three tabs in VIM:

```
# block one
 where c = '123'
 where c = '2345'
 ... 

# block two
set b = 12
set b = 345
...

# block three
update myTable set a = 'abc', 
update myTable set a = '23423', 
...
```

each block contains 100 lines (fragments of SQL query). I would like to concatenate those blocks in to one complete SQL query: block one + block two + block three (100 lines) like this:

```
# sql queries
update myTable set a = 'abc', set b = 12 where c = '123'
update myTable set a = '23423', set b = 345 where c = '2345'
...
```

Just ignore the first line #..., it is just for explanation. I think that Visual Block can be used do that:

1. Yank all the lines in tab "block two";
2. Paste buffer to tab "block three" at the beginning;
3. Yank all the lines in tab "block one";
4. Paste the buffer to tab "block three" at the beginning.

However, I tried to the tip in [Visual Block Mode](http://jvi.sourceforge.net/javahelpset/jvi-vis_block.html)(first two y and p examples), I could not get my expected result. The paste does not concatenate the buffer strings to the block.  Not sure what I did wrong. Or any other alternative ways?

Comment: This could be done easier using a short script I think (python, or possibly bash).

Comment: As an aside, you should be using parameterized queries rather than string concatenation, since sending a plain string opens you up to sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently ran across a [VimCasts](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/selecting-columns-with-visual-block-mode/) episode that describes how to do editing in visual block mode. Check out the video, I believe he describes what you want.

Comment: Yes. I yank the block first, and then P to paste the block to a position where I want to insert the block of text. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Did you try Visual-blockwise (`ctrl-v`)? They have to be the same width lines, but it works.</strike>

```
# Yank the lines from the other file
gg V G 
# Add whitespace to the end
:%s/$/  /
# Select the whitespace at the end of the other file, and paste it
gg $ ctrl-v $ p
```

You may have to make a few changes, but hopefully it gave you some ideas at least.